# Local storage not migrated when moving to crosswalk

Tags: javascript, cordova, cordova-plugins, phonegap, crosswalk

When adding crosswalk (2.4) to my project, local storage is not migrated as said in "You'll need to manually migrate local data when switching between the two (note: this is fixed in Crosswalk 15)"

I have tried to migrate the Local Storage manually from the native webview, but crosswalk seems to overwrite it or something, at least it's very unclear how to do it.

I know the project is not maintained, but someone might be able to help or point me in the right direction. Our project really depends on it right now due to poor performance and available memory in the native webview.

Comment: Do you want this migration to be done for customers who are already using your app on native webview, and you don't want them to lose local storage when they update to the new version with crosswalk?

Comment: Exactly, that's the case i'm trying to solve. To "migrate local storage data".

Comment: What have you tried? Show more on how you did it and what was the result.

Answer (score 2):

You can't migrate data manually from within the Cordova app using JS - the migration needs to be done natively: once the Crosswalk plugin is installed to your Cordova project, your app is using a Crosswalk Webview instead of an Android System Webview, so the local storage data is stored in a completely different location and you have no reference to the original location:

- System Webview (Android 4.4+): `/data/data/[package_id]/Local Storage`
- System Webview (Android 4.3 and below): `/data/data/[package_id]/localstorage`
- Crosswalk: `/data/data/[package_id/app_xwalkcore/Default/Local Storage`

[A commit](https://github.com/crosswalk-project/crosswalk/commit/22170137e73de48c0750810f663c9d0cf484e6e9#diff-c09c01efe9a4b05b65dd344eccd40cf2) was added to Crosswalk to automatically perform migration of all locally-persisted Webview data (including local storage) from the System webview locations to the Crosswalk locations in order to preserve user data when adding Crosswalk to an app that had previously stored data in a System Webview. Looking at the [commit history](https://github.com/crosswalk-project/crosswalk/commits/master), this made it into [Crosswalk 24.53.592.0](https://github.com/crosswalk-project/crosswalk/commit/0646da1c536cd204796ab9ffe8265eff98030c88) so updating to that version or above should pull in the native migration code.

If updating the Crosswalk version is not possible, you could always create your own migration plugin based on mine: [cordova-plugin-crosswalk-data-migration](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-crosswalk-data-migration). 
However, you'd be looking to migrate in the other direction since my plugin is designed to migrated **from** Crosswalk back **to** the System Webview.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and sorry for the late replay, I have not been at work for a while.

Is it really possible to set the crosswalk version to 24.53.592.0? Crosswalk them self says: "As of February 2017, Crosswalk is not being developed anymore. The last Crosswalk relase is 23."

I have tried this preference:

`<platform name="android">
        <preference name="xwalkVersion" value="24.53.592.0" />
</platform>`

Comment: Crosswalk 24 was not published as a release so you would need to build it directly from the github repo: see [Build crosswalk cordova android](https://github.com/crosswalk-project/crosswalk-website/wiki/Build-crosswalk-cordova-android-(optional)) and [Building Crosswalk](https://crosswalk-project.org/contribute/building_crosswalk.html)

Comment: It seems really messy compared to just using the plugin for my release process and i'm afraid i don't really understand it. Will see how I move forward.